# Converting DT_WSTR to DT_DATE

Tags: ssis-2012, date-conversion

So Im pretty new to this stuff but working through a few issues. What I am trying to do is pull source files from a Flat File Source but the dates in all my source files are formatted to YYYYMMDD so I have inserted a Derived Column task and created an expression to format all the columns with dates YYYYMMDD to YYYY-MM-DD and that looks like this:

```
LEFT(ISSUE_DT,4) + "-" + SUBSTRING(ISSUE_DT,5,2) + "-" + RIGHT(ISSUE_DT,2)
```

All is good with that except it's in the data type of DT_WSTR so I dropped in a Columns Conversion task to convert DT_WSTR to DT_DATE but I keep getting the following error:

```
[Columns Conversion [1]] Error: Data conversion failed while converting 
column "ISSUE_DT Formatted" (258) to column "Copy of ISSUE_DT Formatted" 
(16).  The conversion returned status value 2 and status text "The value 
could not be converted because of a potential loss of data.".
```

I have tried opening the advanced editor and navigated to the Data Conversion Output Columns and tried changing the DataType under Data Type Properties to DT_DATE but still the same error..

What am I missing or doing wrong??

[Data Flow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Iyz3.png)

[Formatted Dates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FuuB3.png)

[Column Conversion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YC855.png)

[Column Conversion Advanced Editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QjsUM.png)

Comment: Hello. If there is no error with converting one of your YYYY-MM-DD samples to date in MS SQL, so this error is for one the records in data which is not like YYYY-MM-DD.

Answer (score 1):

You have some dates that are not in the format that your SSIS package is expecting. Perhaps single-digit months or days do not have a leading 0. That scenario would definitely cause this specific error.

Take today for example, if single-digit months or days did not have leading zeroes, you have 2018918 instead of 20180918. Without seeing the data, I can't guarantee that this is the exact issue, but it is something like this. The error is occurring when converting the string to the date. So continuing with the example above, after your Derived Column ISSUED_DT formatted would have a value of '2018-91-18' which of course is not a valid date and causes the error.